# Python JSON change single quotes to double quotes leave in-string quotes alone

Tags: python, json, pandas, quotes, double-quotes

We have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from json import JSONDecodeError

json_as_str_list = [
    "[{'key1': 312, 'name': 'Simple name'}]",
    "[{'key1': 981, 'name': 'Name n' quote'}]",
    np.nan
]
d = {'json_as_str': json_as_str_list}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


    json_as_str
0   [{'key1': 312, 'name': 'Simple name'}]
1   [{'key1': 981, 'name': 'Name n' quote'}]
2   NaN
```

After the import `json_as_str` column is a list of strings but I want it to be a list of JSON objects. I've written a function which should return a list of empty JSON objects given a string or an empty list given a `np.nan`:

```
 def convert_to_JSON_helper(json_str):
    if isinstance(json_str, str):
        json_str = json_str.replace("'", '"')
        try:
            return json.loads(json_str)
        except JSONDecodeError:
            print(json_str)
            return []
    else:
        return []
```

Current implementation doesn't handle in-string single quotes (as in the second row of the dataframe). How should I modify the function so that it works as expected?

The current output I get while using `df['json_as_str'].apply(convert_to_JSON_helper)`:

```
0    [{'key1': 312, 'name': 'Simple name'}]
1                                        []
2                                        []
Name: json_as_str, dtype: object
```

The output I'd like to get:

```
0    [{'key1': 312, 'name': 'Simple name'}]
1  [{'key1': 981, 'name': 'Name n' quote'}]
2                                        []
Name: json_as_str, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the function but the string. You typed a `\` to quote the single quote, but it was plain useless because a single \ in a string quotes the following character (here the quote) and let it go in the string. Demo:

```
>>> a = " a 'b' 'c\'d' "
>>> a
" a 'b' 'c'd' "
```

The back slash has just be eaten in the string.

Anyway you should not try to convert quotes in a general way. Because of all the possible corner cases, you will have to build a dedicated (and complex) parser. So my advice is that you should just insert a correct JSON string in your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Granted, it was by mistake while creating an example. The  problem is that the JSON string is given as I've described (except for the backslash) and I must somehow find a way to change single quotes to double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the convert a string (with single ') to dict.

```
import ast

data = ast.literal_eval("{'a' : 12, 'c' : 'd'}")
print(data)
print(type(data))
```

output

```
{'a': 12, 'c': 'd'}
<type 'dict'>
```